# Binary Bomb Lab Phase 3 Switch Function Confusion

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

This is my first time consulting Stack Overflow so I'm sorry if my formatting isn't the best. I'm working on solving Phase 3 of the Binary Bomb Lab where you have to read through assembly code to come up with a "passcode" that defuses the bomb.

I've figured out that I need two inputs for this phase in the format `%d %d`. I'm pretty sure the first number can be any integer from 1-7, but I'm not sure how to figure out what the second input should be.

I know that there's multiple answers depending on the first number you choose, and that you're supposed to figure out the second input by inspecting the switch statement code. However, I'm unsure of how to do this.

Both line +70 and line +81 invoke a switch function (which I'm assuming is the equivalent to a jump table / switch statement), but I'm not sure how I should be inspecting it. Any tips or advice would help. Thank you so much!

[image: Assembly Dump]

Comment: Hi Nina Wang, could you please replace the image of the assembly dump by the actual text of the assembly dump formatted  using the `{}`  button ? using images of text instead of the text itself is not recommended. Thank you.

Comment: *I'm not sure how I should be inspecting it.* - `disas func_switch`, or find it in the `objdump -drwC` output.  Or single-step into it when you run the program; that's why you're using GDB in the first place instead of just static disassembly, right?

Comment: (And BTW, if you prefer Intel-syntax, you can use `objdump -drwC -Mintel` or gdb `set disassembly-flavor intel`.)